# MVVMCross: Bind nested properties in android xml

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Supose i have this ViewModel

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public Location Location {get;set;}
}
```

and the Location object

```
public class Location
{
    public decimal Latitude {get;set;}
    public decimal Longitude {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to bind to the property Address of the Location object inside PersonViewModel, something like this

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    mvx:MvxBind="Text Location.Address"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

When done with simple properties everything works fine, meaning everything is correctly configure, is just with this case.

How is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: This seems perfectly right. I use the same structure to do some databindings.

Comment: Does PersonViewModel inherit from MvxViewModel ?

Comment: As you previously mentioned, the code described is working correctly. After some debugging,  I discovered that the json I'm using to load the object sometimes is deleted. To read the file I'm using IMvxFileStore.TryReadTextFile() and the file is located in data/data/{appnamespace}/files.

Now I need to check why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned by Martijn00, the code above is correct. The cause of the error was different.

I'm using a json file to load the objects. I used the file's plugin default location (data/data/{appnamespace}/files).

```
var fileStore = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>();
var fileContent = "";
fileStore.TryReadTextFile("Person.json", out fileContent);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonViewModel>(fileContent);
```

As described by the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html), this route is the device's internal memory and is deleted when the application is uninstalled. This means that every time the applications is re-deployed, this route is re-created deleting the json file and hence causing the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to throw an exception.

Comment: Try http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/preserving-data-during-xamarinandroid.html ?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.